# Hashing Access time with multi variable key

Tags: algorithm, performance, hash, hashmap, hashtable

Suppose a dictionary has 2 variable keys instead of 1 like

```
dictionary[3,5] = Something
dictionry[1,2] = Something
dictionary[3,1] = Something
```

Would the search time still be O(1).In case I need to find if dictionary[1,5] exists would it yield constant time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify - the expected result of looking up [1, 5] would be to not find anything?

Comment: Yes It should return NULL but what would the time complexity be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a lookup in a hash table, the cost involved is the cost of

- hashing the item to look up, and
- comparing that item against (an expected O(1) number of) other other entries in the table.

We can write the expected cost of a hash table lookup as O(hash-cost + compare-cost).

In your case, the cost of hashing a pair instead of a single element is still O(1) - just hash each element of the pair and apply some hash combination step to the two values. Similarly, the cost of comparing two pairs is also O(1) (assuming each individual element of the pair can be compared in constant time). As a result, a lookup will still be (expected) constant time.

The above argument generalizes to any fixed size triple as a key. You typically have to worry about the cost of hashing and comparing keys when they have variable length, as would be the case if you were hashing strings with no length restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is not new. In usual, you can have a dictionary with string keys. If you see string as an array of characters, you have a list of chars as key. So, in the same situation, you can say your dictionary works in `O(1)` too (if length of string is constant).

Comment: @templatetypedef If length of strings is constant, it would be O(1).